# Why the bitcoin address is not valid in any of the testNet faucet

Tags: testnet, bitcoinj, address-generation, java

I develop a simple Java/Maven/JSP app for bitcoin and generated the address 
    167Bqf3Mi3gnfhw5DhCfoYNTMxqANt3Zky 
I would like to send some money to this address from a bitcoin testnet faucet. I feel it weird that none of the testNet faucet out there seems to recognize the address and indicate it as invalid. Funny thing is I used the same code for generating the address that is provided in the `BitcoinJ` github page.

How should I approach from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testnet uses a [different address format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes) than the main network. Testnet addresses start with an "m" or "n".
The address you are using starts with a "1" and is therefore for the main network. This is why the testnet faucets say the address is invalid.

From the [documentation of BitcoinJ](https://bitcoinj.github.io/getting-started-java), it seems that you can configure your code to use the testnet with:

> params = TestNet3Params.get();

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps me a lot. The reason it was created in the first place is that I have used `public static NetworkParameters networkParameters = MainNetParams.get();`. I later changed the code to `public static NetworkParameters networkParameters = TestNet3Params.get();` and  `else if (networkParameters == TestNet3Params.get()) {

            bitcoin.useTor();
//            bitcoin.setDiscovery(new HttpDiscovery(networkParameters, URI.create("http://localhost:8080/peers"),

        }`. New test net address `n3xE28g8cmVYNU5VeGFazoqfGj2PaZUXYN `

Comment: Indeed, the new address seems to be a valid testnet address :) . Glad to be of help!